# Synchronising threads for multiple readers / single writer in Clojure

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure

I have some non-thread-safe code (a writer to shared data) that can only be called from multiple threads in a serialised manner, but I don't want to block any other thread-safe work (multiple readers) when this code is not being called.

This is essentially a multiple reader / single writer type locking situation where writers need to exclude both readers and other writers.

i.e. I have two functions:

```
(defn reader-function [] ....) // only reads from shared data

(defn writer-function [] ....) // writes to shared data
```

And a number of threads that are running (possibly in a loop) the following:

```
(do 
  (reader-function)
  ...
  (writer-function))
```

If any single thread is executing the writer function, all the other threads must block. i.e. at any one time either:

- one thread is executing the
  writer and all
  others are blocked
- multiple threads are 
  executing the reader function, possibly some threads are
  blocked waiting to execute
  the writer once all readers are completed

What's the best way to achieve this kind of synchronisation in Clojure?

Answer (score 3):

Put your data in a `ref`.  The data should be a Clojure data structure (not a Java class).  Use `dosync` to create a transaction around the read and write.

Example.  Because you split your writer into a separate function, that function must modify a ref with something like an `alter`.  Doing so requires a transaction (`dosync`).  You could rely on writer being called only in a dosync but you can also put a dosync inside the write and rely on nested transactions doing what you want - this makes writer safe to call either in or out of a transaction.

```
(defn reader [shared] 
  (println "I see" @shared))

(defn writer [shared item]
  (dosync 
    (println "Writing to shared")
    (alter shared conj item)))

;; combine the read and the write in a transaction
(defn combine [shared item]
  (dosync 
    (reader shared)
    (writer shared item)))

;; run a loop that adds n thread-specific items to the ref
(defn test-loop [shared n]
  (doseq [i (range n)]
    (combine shared (str (System/identityHashCode (Thread/currentThread)) "-" i))
    (Thread/sleep 50)))

;; run t threads adding n items in parallel
(defn test-threaded [t n]
  (let [shared (ref [])]
    (doseq [_ (range t)]
      (future (test-loop shared n)))))
```

Run the test with something like `(test-threaded 3 10)`.

More info here: http://clojure.org/refs

You didn't ask about this case, but it's important to note that anyone can read the shared ref by derefing it at any time.  This does not block concurrent writers.

Comment: @mikera, Is the writing a side effect of an external process? In that case I don't think refs can do the job here, which is only used for same process shared state. I only know of using a partial solution using agents.

Comment: hi Alex, thanks for the answer! looks great as a 100% Clojure approach, however the issue is that the writers are executing side-effectful code (actually in a Java library) that I can't directly control. Hence it doesn't play nicely with Clojure transactions and I need to somehow mirror the locking requirements of the library....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock. This class allow you to have multiple readers that do not contend with each other on one writer at a time.

Comment: RRWL will do that but you should not use them to solve this problem in Clojure.  If you use RRWL to protect your data, you are not taking advantage of Clojure's immutable data structures, refs, or STM.  Clojure's refs of Clojure data structures already allow multiple readers.  Because they are immutable and persistent they can be deref'ed any time w/o blocking writers.  Read http://clojure.org/refs .

Comment: Thanks Ralph! Looks like it is along the lines of what I need. Any idea if there is a Clojure-equivalent or will I need to use the Java interop to get at this functionality?

Comment: @mikera: As Alex Miller said in his comment, refs behave like this, but as far as I know, Clojure does not have specific functions to do this.